# How to implement stripe as payment gateway for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-web, flutter-packages

I have never worked with payment gateways. Unfortunalality, all stripe packages do not support the flutter web. Where do I start? How do I make a function to process one-time billing and recurring abonnement? And how do I stop a recurring payment?
Maybe is it possible to adapt the current stripe packages for the web?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Iframe for load html/js scripts on flutter web app,

```
//register view factory
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'stripe-html',
      (int viewId) {
         IFrameElement element=IFrameElement();
        [...]
         element.src='html/stripe.html';
);


return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'stripe-html'),
          );
    }));
```

Here's an example for implementing a payment gateway in flutter web app :
[Flutter Web: Razorpay Payment Gateway Integration](https://itnext.io/flutter-web-razorpay-payment-gateway-integration-792d6e015409) with [Stripe API/JS](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js)